# How to repartition the main disk without disabling Windows recovery partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, recovery

I want to add a partition to my main disk, the one that has C drive.
I am running Windows 10.
Currently, to the right of the C drive I have my Recovery partition.
I do know how to shrink the C drive and then move the Recovery partition to the left of the empty space. But if I do that, experience shows that the Recovery environment will become disabled, and I will get the error “Could not find the recovery environment” if I try to reset Windows.
Is there a way I can add a partition but not mess up the Recovery environment? Or is that just the way it is?

Comment: Why not just use Windows to re-partition the disk.  Use less space for the Data partition if you wish to do this.

Comment: Why are you moving the recovery partition.  Shrink the C drive, and create a new partition in freed space without moving the recovery partition.

Comment: The problem I am dealing with is that Windows doesn't find the recovery partition anymore, if it is no longer adjacent to the C drive, where it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

The Recovery partition can be moved, but the procedure is a bit
complicated. You will find it described in detail in the article
[Moving Windows Recovery Partition Correctly](https://thedxt.ca/2023/06/moving-windows-recovery-partition-correctly/),
so here is just the summary:

- Disable the Recovery partition : `reagentc /disable`.
  This will move it into the file `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery\Winre.wim`.
- Run `diskpart` in CMD as Admin, select disk and Recovery partition
  and delete it via `delete partition override`.
- Use Disk Management to resize partition `C:` and create any
  new partition you like, leaving about 1 GB of unallocated space.
- Still in Disk Management, create a new Simple Volume over
  the unallocated space without a drive-letter.
- In `diskpart`, select the new partition and:

  - For a GPT disk (MBR is described in the article),
    set the partition as a Recovery partition:
    `set id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`
  - Hide and flag as a required partition:
    `gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001`
  - exit `diskpart`
- Re-enable the recovery partition : `reagentc /enable`.

I suggest before starting, to create a backup image of the disk and have
a boot USB that can restore it in emergency.
One such tool is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html)
and
[Create AOMEI Bootable CD/DVD/USB Based on Windows PE](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html).

Answer (score 0):

use right click and run diskmanager built in windows;
use resize main partion; apply;
if all good now you can create new partion on empty slot;

---

if not able to resize sys drive - free some space in windows; remove not needed files; clean tmp etc;

---

if still windows lock something and not able to resize - use free acronis version or partition magic apps;
that tools also can crate bootable cd or usb...